# TTFB for node server req/res

Tags: node.js, performance, time-to-first-byte

I have a node server as a Backend for frontend. We make request from node to a java server for HTTP. We are facing latency issues and suspect node taking time to read the response(some are html responses). For performance we are using node performance.now for measuring time between request and complete response.

But, is there any node functionality we can use to check when the response started coming to node server, like time to first byte for node server?